# How to set EpiServer.Url property programmatically

Tags: url, episerver, episerver-7

On my BlockData type I've property of type EpiServer.Url

`public virtual EpiServer.Url Url { get; set; }`

From EditMode I'm able to set it for concrete PageData instance, but i'm not sure how to set it in code having only ContentReference?

Thanks in advance for help.

**EDIT**:

The one way I found to do this is through:

```
var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();
int contentReferenceId = 69;
ContentReference contentRef = new ContentReference(contentReferenceId);
block.Url = urlResolver.GetUrl(contentRef, language.Code);
```

I would be glad if somebody could point me a better solution if there is any.

Comment: Like Johan suggests, you don't want to save an actual URL, rather just a reference to the content.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the EpiServer.Url property in EditMode gives you ability to set it as an link to page in EpiServer or a link to external page or even something else. This is the reason why I didn't accepted Johan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way `EpiServer.Url` class is made (see `public static implicit operator Url(string url)` implementation) the only way to set value of it in the code is by setting string value:

```
var url = "some url";
block.Url = url;
```

So the way you suggest (`ContentReference` and `IUrlResolver`) in your question works correct, but I believe I have a better solution which in some cases (when you have `PageData` instance available) might be much simpler:

`EPiServer.Core.PageData` has `public virtual string LinkURL` property. You can use this value and set it as your `Url` value:

`block.Url = articlePage.LinkURL; //articlePage is instance of PageData`

EpiServer will understand that this is internal link to some content and will set proper link to content - so whenever you move or rename your content `block.Url` will still point to valid content.

Comment: Dzięki Tomek :)

Answer (score 1):

```
publich virtual ContentReference Url { get; set; }
```

Or if you only want pages:

```
publich virtual PageReference Url { get; set; }
```